# MS Access Database SQL Query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, ms-access

I have 3 Tables called Invoice, Customer and Company. I want to merge this 3 tables into single using *Query*. In Invoice Table contain Customer Id and Company Id. How to Join 3 tables ?

I tried Invoice and Customer Table working fine with this query. But I dont have idea to add 3rd table with this.

```
SELECT RPT_Invoice_Less.InvoiceNumber, RPT_Invoice_Less.Terms,
    RPT_Invoice_Less.Invoicedate, RPT_Invoice_Less.OurQuote,
    RPT_Invoice_Less.SalesPerson, RPT_Customer.CustomerName,
    RPT_Customer.CustomerId, RPT_Customer.ContactPerson,
    RPT_Customer.BillingAddress, RPT_Customer.DeliveryAddress,
    RPT_Invoice_Less.OrderNumber, RPT_Invoice_Less.ShippingBy,
    RPT_Invoice_Less.ShipReferenceNo, RPT_Invoice_Less.Notes,
    RPT_Invoice_Less.Price, RPT_Invoice_Less.Discount,
    RPT_Invoice_Less.Shipping, RPT_Invoice_Less.Tax,
    RPT_Invoice_Less.GrandTotal, RPT_Invoice_Less.Company
FROM RPT_Invoice_Less
INNER JOIN RPT_Customer
ON RPT_Invoice_Less.CustomerId = RPT_Customer.CustomerId;
```

this code working fine for 2 tables

```
SELECT RPT_Invoice_Less.InvoiceNumber, RPT_Invoice_Less.Terms, RPT_Invoice_Less.Invoicedate, RPT_Invoice_Less.OurQuote, RPT_Invoice_Less.SalesPerson, RPT_Customer.CustomerName, RPT_Customer.CustomerId, RPT_Customer.ContactPerson, RPT_Customer.BillingAddress, RPT_Customer.DeliveryAddress, RPT_Invoice_Less.OrderNumber, RPT_Invoice_Less.ShippingBy, RPT_Invoice_Less.ShipReferenceNo, RPT_Invoice_Less.Notes, RPT_Invoice_Less.Price, RPT_Invoice_Less.Discount, RPT_Invoice_Less.Shipping, RPT_Invoice_Less.Tax, RPT_Invoice_Less.GrandTotal, RPT_OrionSystem.Company, RPT_OrionSystem.CompanyId
FROM RPT_Invoice_Less 
INNER JOIN RPT_Customer 
ON RPT_Invoice_Less.CustomerId = RPT_Customer.CustomerId
INNER JOIN RPT_OrionSystem
ON RPT_Invoice_Less.CompanyId = RPT_OrionSystem.CompanyId;
```

This code showing syntax error.

Help me to add 3rd *Company* table to this.

Comment: To answer your question we need to know where is the relation between the Company table and one of the other two tables. Something like a CompanyID in RPT_Customer table for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that you have a `CompanyID` field (or something like that) in the `RPT_Customer` table or in the  `RPT_Invoice_Less`, it is just a matter to add another INNER JOIN

```
....
FROM ((RPT_Invoice_Less
INNER JOIN RPT_Customer
ON RPT_Invoice_Less.CustomerId = RPT_Customer.CustomerId)
INNER JOIN RPT_OrionSystem 
ON  RPT_Invoice_Less.CompanyID = RPT_OrionSystem.CompanyID)
```

Comment: Hi, I edited my question now I tried same as you mentioned but getting syntax error

Comment: Try adding a couple of parenthesys

Comment: Where to add ? I tried already that I add brackets on `(RPT_Invoice_Less.CustomerId = RPT_Customer.CustomerId)` and `(RPT_Customer.CompanyID = RPT_CompanyData.CompanyID)` still same syntax error

Comment: Answer updated refresh, and remove the semicolon at the end. Could you add the exact C# code around this call?

Comment: Yeah that's working fine after adding parenthesys . This Query I used in MS Access Database only. Then I populate to C#. Thankz a lot.